# How to join two large table into one in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table people

```
    Name  Id            Age Sex  Country    
    Ankit ankitgautam24 17   M   India
    John  john321       71   M   France
    Will  willsmith     42   M   USA
    Arti  artisingh     67   F   Pakistan
   .....3.5 million records......
```

And another table Restriction

```
Country        Sex      Allow
France         F       Allowed
France         M       Restricted
India          F       Restricted
India          M       Allowed
Pakistan       F       Restricted
....for each country ......
```

Now I want to convert it to table Useraccount whose structure should be

```
    Name  Id            Age Sex  Country  Allow   
    Ankit ankitgautam24 17   M   India    Allowed
    John  john321       71   M   France   Restricted 
    Will  willsmith     42   M   USA      Allowed
    Arti  artisingh     67   F   Pakistan Allowed
   .....hundreds of thousands of record......
```

What is the correct query to join these two table to one in smartest way

Comment: That way takes how much time?

Comment: It takes 4 standard time units. Seriously though. Your question is unanswerable. It depends on at least a dozen variables you haven't specified (CPU, RAM, Database size, Indexes, Other load on server, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is just a simple, straightforward `JOIN`, and it won't take much time:

```
SELECT p.Name, p.Id, p.Age, p.Sex, p.Country,
       r.Allow 
FROM People p 
INNER JOIN Restriction r ON p.Country = r.Country
```

`JOIN` here will be the more efficient way to do this, but to make it more efficient, instead of joining the two tables on `Country` name, you will better off add `CountryID` and join them on this column instead. So your table `People` should look like:

- `Name`.
- `Id`.
- `Age`.
- `CountryId` Constraint foreign key references `Restrictions` table (`CountryId`).

And the `Restrictions` table:

- `CountryID`.
- `IsAllwoed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well:

```
SELECT p.Name, 
       p.Id, 
       p.Age, 
       p.Sex, 
       p.Country, 
       r.Allow, 
       r.Country 
from people p, Restriction r 
where r.Country=p.Country
```